# NTP timestamps in Python

Tags: python, ntp

I need to generate a timestamp in NTP format in Python.  Specifically, I need to calculate the number of seconds since 1st January 1900, as a 32-bit number.  (NTP timestamps are actually 64 bits, with the other 32 bits representing fractions of seconds - I'm not worried about this part).

How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import datetime
diff = datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
timestamp = diff.days*24*60*60+diff.seconds
timestamp
# returns
# 3531049334
```

*(note that `timedelta.total_seconds()` is not available in python3)*

Comment: Just to note - `timedelta.total_seconds()` is available under Python 2.7 and Python >= 3.2, it's just the earlier 2.x, 3.0 and 3.1 releases that lacked it.

Answer (score 3):

From the python [ntplib](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ntplib/) :

```
SYSTEM_EPOCH = datetime.date(*time.gmtime(0)[0:3])
NTP_EPOCH = datetime.date(1900, 1, 1)
NTP_DELTA = (SYSTEM_EPOCH - NTP_EPOCH).days * 24 * 3600

def ntp_to_system_time(date):
    """convert a NTP time to system time"""
    return date - NTP_DELTA

def system_to_ntp_time(date):
    """convert a system time to a NTP time"""
    return date + NTP_DELTA
```

and this is used like this :

```
ntp_time = system_to_ntp_time(time.time())
```

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at `ntplib`, which is available via PyPi:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ntplib/

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime

(datetime.utcnow() - datetime(1900, 1, 1)).total_seconds()
```

That returns a `float` which you can truncate in the obvious way. Be sure to put in a check that the result is `<= 2**32-1`, since your program is bound to break in 2036.